How is Euler's number related to gambling and oddsmaking?
Bernoulli supposedly discovered 'e' in two places...  continuously compounded interest, and in probability...
Suppose I have a one-in-a-million chance of winning a game, but I try a million times....
Bernoulli realized that the odds would be, for extremely long odds, 63.21205588...%, or 1-(1÷e).
Why is that?  Why is Euler's number, usually associated with any kind of continuously compounded growth, also associated with odds?

Are you confused about the proofs of these facts? Or are you asking for some sort of “deeper” meaning?

In fact $1-\left(1-\frac{1}{1000000}\right)^{1000000} \approx 0.6321207428$ so a little more than value you give for $1-\frac1e$
